# How to pass a string value from resource file to a ConverterParameter?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter

I want to pass this resource, that looks like this in code:

```
AppResources.lbCountry;
```

as `ConverterParameter` here:

```
<Label Text="{Binding SelectedCountry.Name, Converter={StaticResource nullToResourceConv}, ConverterParameter={--}}"  >
```

**EDIT**

`lbCountry` in the `AppResources`:

```
internal static string lbCountry {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("lbCountry", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
```

`Resx` namespace definition:

```
xmlns:Resx="clr-namespace:XamApp.Resources"
```

but this doesn't work:

```
ConverterParameter={x:Static Resx:AppResources.lbCountry}}
```

Error:

> x:Static: unable to find a public static field, static property,
>   const or enum value named lbCountry in Resx:AppResources

Comment: The error says it failed to find a **public** field, so try changing it to be `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ConverterParameter={x:Static myNameSpace:AppResources.lbCountry}
```

Also make sure the property is `public`

Comment: I got this error:

x:Static: unable to find a public static field, static property, const or enum value named lbCountry in Resx:AppResources

Comment: @MohamedAhmed Is `lbCountry` static? What does your `Resx` `xmlns` look like (the namespace declaration in your XAML page for `Resx`)?

Comment: I've amended the question

Comment: @MohamedAhmed The error says it failed to find a **public** field, so try changing it to be `public`